# Android GPS takes too much time to get the location coordinates

Tags: android, gps

> Here, GPS takes half an hour or more (time) to get the current location coordinates.
>
> How can I use GPS from GPS_SATELLITES and GPS _NETWORK_PROVIDERS
>   simultaneously in the same context and get the value of the recent
>   GPS?

```
public class ImageFile extends Activity{

    LocationListener listner;
Location location;
LocationManager locationManager ;
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 10 * 1; // 1 minute

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.branchreport_layout);


    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    listner = new MyLocationListner();
    isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if(isGPSEnabled==false&&isNetworkEnabled==false)
    {
        showSettingsAlert();
    }
    if (isGPSEnabled) 
    {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "GPS",
                "Fetching latitude and longitude...", true);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,listner);   


    }
    else if (isNetworkEnabled)
    {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "GPS",
                "Fetching latitude and longitude...", true);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,listner);
    }



public class MyLocationListner implements LocationListener {

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        x = location.getLatitude();
        y = location.getLongitude();

        if((x!=0) && (y!=0))
        {
            progress.dismiss();

            locationManager.removeUpdates(listner);
            Geocoder gCoder = new Geocoder(ImageFile.this);

            try {
                addresses = gCoder.getFromLocation(x, y, 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                Log.d("TestTag", "Locality: " + addresses.get(0).getLocality()+"getAddressLine"+addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)+",getAdminArea"+addresses.get(0).getAdminArea()+",getSubLocality"+addresses.get(0).getSubLocality());
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
}
```

}

Comment: GPS fixed min three Satellite and then give you exact location. Always take time. Betterto do in background/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GPS is always slow, so i'll suggest to use `Android Location API using Google Play Services`.

**Steps**

> First check for availability of Google Play Services by calling in onResume() of the Activity
>
> Once play services are available on the device, build the GoogleApiClient.
>
> Connect to google api client by calling mGoogleApiClient.connect() in onStart() method. By calling this, `onConnectionFailed()`, `onConnected()` and `onConnectionSuspended()` (GooglePlayServiceListeners) will be triggered depending upon the connection status.
>
> Once google api is successfully connected, displayLocation() should be called in onConnected() method to get the current location.

This is how we build the GoogleApiClient

```
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    }
```

**displayLocation()**

```
private void displayLocation() {
 
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
 
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
 
            lblLocation.setText(latitude + ", " + longitude);
 
        } else {
 
            lblLocation
                    .setText("(Couldn't get the location. Make sure location is enabled on the device)");
        }
    }
```

A perfect explanation of the above methods and steps can be found [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/) .also check the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

Comment: Instead of this using Google Play Services, Is there any solution for above issue...

Comment: I think the only way to retrv location is through GPS and Google Play Service. I never able to rtrv location from `NETWORK_PROVIDER`. I am not pro in Android and all i knw is this.

Comment: Google Play Services, Location API (FusedLocation) are not very friendly in the long run. I went though hell to get 'Single Update' working on Location API. Location Manager is good for Single Updates, but takes too much time. Hence, I would propose use a combination of both: For first load, use FusedLocation. Once done, remove callbacks and initialize Location Manager for further updates. (I'm talking in context of Single Updates)